# Placing temporary objects into vectors in classes and if it's bad practice

Tags: c++, class, oop

Cheers! I have a question that regards something that I think might be considered "bad practice", but I would like to make sure.

Let's suppose I have a class that contains inside it a vector, in which I want to store Objects of e.g. Students, which are classes that only hold some integers, nothing fancy inside them, such as pointers or else. When I create the superclass e.g. `class A {};` which holds this vector, I want to initialize the vector with some students for example, when the constructor is called. So I create a temporary object e.g. `Student to_enter;`, which I then push inside the vector. This vector will be used by other classes, in order to remove or add even more students. I know that the temporary object will go out of scope, when the scope of the constructor is ended, but I think the object is created by copy construction when put inside the vector, so I think that there is no problem when a future function will try to change these Objects (that have been created by copy construction).

However, is this correct? Or am I just lucky that there has not been an error so far? **I guess what I am asking, is if the object inside the vector affect the lifetime of the object, so that it can be changed later with no problem.** Also, is this a bad practice and I will have to put pointers inside, or is this not necessary? Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
class Student{
    .....
}

std::vector<Student> vec;
```

and wonder what happens if you do

```
 void func(std::vector &vec){
      Student s1;
      vec.push_back(s1);
  }
  func(vec);
```

will vec contain a valid Student object

Yes, s1 will be copied into vec.

But dont do this, its very inefficient for non trivial objects. `std::shared_ptr` is you friend. Do this instead

```
class Student{
    .....
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>> vec;

 void func(std::vector &vec){
      auto s1 = std::make_shared<Student>();
      vec.push_back(s1);
  }
  func(vec);
```

Now your student objects are not being copied. Instead you have them on the heap, nicely managed for you.

BTW I would do

```
using PStudent = std::shared_ptr<Student>;
std::vector<PStudent> vec;
```

just to reduce the typing and visual noise

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can understand this is inefficient, but is it okay to do? Because you didn't end your sentence on if the vector will contain a valid Student object. I suppose because of the copying it is valid, but I would like to be sure of it. Thanks